# How to Render Partial View To String

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, rendering, umbraco, partial-views

I tried to convert Umbraco Children item into a PartialView but i want it to return as a string and not as a partial View.

I read a lot in the forums and i've got errors when i'm trying these examples.

I have few different templates which i want to get from the controller as the user get inside to the site. 
every few hours, i mean, once in few hours to check via Ajax if there is new items for this time. the ajax working properly.

I get an error that say "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." and i don't really know what about is the error, is the model? is the partial name? what's wrong? or how to make it work.

Here is my code

```
foreach (dynamic item in rangeTime.Children)
                    {
                        var docType = item.ContentType.Alias;
                        var partialViewToShow = docType.ToString().Trim().ToLower().Replace(" ", "") == "birthday" ? "BDay" : "ContentPage";

                        st.Append(string.Format("<div class=\"custom-item\" data-time-to-show=\"{0}\">", item.slideTime));
                        st.Append(RenderPartialViewToString(partialViewToShow, item));
                        st.Append("</div>");
                    }
```

which call to this function: (fail on "viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);")

```
 protected string RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
            viewName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

        ViewData.Model = model;

        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
            ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw); // FAIL HERE

            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What sorts of errors do you get when it fails on `viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);`?

Comment: Hi @bowserm, This is the error i get:

"An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpCompileException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: External component has thrown an exception."

Comment: Sounds like maybe the error is in the Partial View and not in the code you pasted above? Can you report back with what's going on inside the PartialView you are trying to render? Maybe as a test, just try throwing that PartialView onto the page instead of doing the fancy string work to see if it renders correctly. My guess is that it can't compile the razor in your PartialView.

Comment: @bowserm You  are right, I solved it by change the partial view to use model xxx.yyy instead of inherits.

Thank you very much dude.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the HttpCompileException means that the system was unable to render the PartialView because it could not compile the razor correctly.

I suggest adding the PartialView to the page using

```
foreach (dynamic item in rangeTime.Children)
{
    var docType = item.ContentType.Alias;
    var partialViewToShow = docType.ToString().Trim().ToLower().Replace(" ", "") == "birthday" ? "BDay" : "ContentPage";

    Html.Partial(partialViewToShow, item)
}
```

to see if you can get it to render before trying to render it as a string. Otherwise, maybe the inner exception will have more details.